# Interview: sumPairs(array) output the sum of all summed pairs in O(n) time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I recently got asked this question in an interview and was only able to give a quadratic solution:

> Given an array with n numbers. Give an algorithm (sumPairs) to find   the
>   cumulative sum of the sum of all pairs of numbers. The algorithm
>   should be O(n) time.
>
> For example: sumPairs([1,2,3,4]):
>
> All pairs are: (1+2) + (1+3) + (1+4) + (2+3) + (2+4) + (3+4)
>
> Sum of all summed pairs: (1+2) + (1+3) + (1+4) + (2+3) + (2+4) + (3+4)
>   = 30

My approach was to generate all 2-tuples, NC2 (N choose 2), and maintain a running total of their sums. However, I am not sure how I could go about doing it in linear time. To my knowledge, there exists n*(n-1)/2 elements for a list of size n. How could this be possible in linear time?

Comment: In an interview, be prepared for a _very_ simple warm-up question: if your answer is not, think again (the question _might_ be hard …). Let's hope this is what this was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to generate the tupples, you can just add each element (n-1) times:

```
sum = 0
for each x:
  sum = sum + x*(n-1)
```

This is based on the fact that each element is added exactly once with each other element, so it is being added total of n-1 times.

Comment: Your answer totally does work but can you please explain how did you arrive at (n-1). Please.

Comment: @Shahzeb I explained it, you add each pair `(x+y)`, that means each element `x` is added with each of other elements, and once with each of them (note it doesn't matter if it's `x+y` or `y+x`). Since there are `n-1` other elements, `x` is added exactly `n-1` times.

Comment: Then, you can postpone the multiplication till the end.